# <Android> Full screen mode is broken and a transparent navigation bar appears when alert is made

Tags: java, android, android-studio, fullscreen

I'm developing application for android tablet and wants it to be always keeping full screen mode.
I set flags for that, but when the alert dialog appears it breaks.
When it first appears it keeps full screen, however, when alert dialog is made again, the full screen mode is broken and a transparent navigation bar appears.
Why does the full screen mode fluctuate? Below is my code.

```
AlertDialog.Builder warning = new AlertDialog.Builder(my_context);
                        View view = ActivityTeetimeDetail.this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(my_alert_layout,null);
                        warning.setView(view);
                        AlertDialog dialog = warning.create();
                        TextView alertTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.setAlertTitle);
                        alertTitle.setText("Text");
                        TextView alertContent = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.setAlertContent);
                        alertContent.setText("Text");
                        Button confirm = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_button_confirm);
                        confirm.setText(R.string.Alert_Confirm);
                        confirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                        Button cancel = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_button_cancel);
                        cancel.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        dialog.setCancelable(true);
                        dialog.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION |
                                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN |
                                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE|
                                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE|
                                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION|
                                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN|
                                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);

                        dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are almost there, you just need to clear the focus from alertdialog that is navigationbar stays hidden.

```
AlertDialog.Builder warning = new AlertDialog.Builder(my_context);
                    View view = ActivityTeetimeDetail.this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(my_alert_layout,null);
                    warning.setView(view);
                    AlertDialog dialog = warning.create();
                    TextView alertTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.setAlertTitle);
                    alertTitle.setText("Text");
                    TextView alertContent = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.setAlertContent);
                    alertContent.setText("Text");
                    Button confirm = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_button_confirm);
                    confirm.setText(R.string.Alert_Confirm);
                    confirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    Button cancel = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_button_cancel);
                    cancel.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    dialog.setCancelable(true);

               // add this to your code.
               dialog.getWindow().
               setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
               WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE);

                    dialog.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION |
                            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN |
                            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE|
                            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE|
                            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION|
                            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN|
                            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);

                    dialog.show();
```

Comment: It definitely works! Thanks! May I ask one more question? When I apply this code, it always hides navigation bar but setCancelable(true) does not work. How can I fix this?

Comment: yes it would not work because we are making the dialog non focusable.

Comment: I made a 0% opacity&invisible layout in the background and set it visible when alert is popped up. I set setOnClickListener for that layout so that background items are not clicked and can dismiss alert dialog with touching background. Thanks for your help!

Comment: that is nice <3